# Understanding a calculation in Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,\langle,\rangle)$ be a Riemannian manifold. If $f$ is a smooth function in $M$ and $X,Y$ are smooth vector fields on $M$ satisfying the following condition
$$f|X|^2=\langle \nabla_YX,X\rangle.$$
Now I have done the following calculation from the above one:
$$f|X|^2=\langle \nabla_YX,X\rangle=\frac{1}{2}Y\langle X,X\rangle=\frac{1}{2}Y|X|^2.$$
Therefore, we get $f=\frac{1}{2}Y$. But the left hand side is a scalar function whereas the right hand side is a vector. I can not find where I have done mistake. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems here your function $f$ is just, on the set of $p\in M$ where $X(p)$ is not zero:
$$
f(p) = \frac{\langle \left(\nabla_YX\right)(p),X(p)\rangle}{\|X(p)\|^2}e
$$
and is extended in some way on $p\in M$ where $X(p)=0$. That is, it measures the covariant derivative in the direction of $Y$ of $X$, renormalized by $X$.

Your mistake is in your understanding of the notation $f\|X\|^2$, as if $f$ was a function with variable $\|X\|^2$. But it is not, and this notation just says that the product of the two functions $f$ and $\|X\|^2$ is equal to the right hand side. THe only input we could give to $f$ is $p \in M$.

Comment: Yes I understand. But is my result $f=(1/2)Y$ correct where X is not zero?

Comment: No it is not. What is true is that $f = \frac{Y\cdot \|X\|^2}{2\|X\|^2}$. Remember $f$ is a function, not a vector field.